# dropdownt is not showing in navbar

Tags: html, css

This is my whole code. im just wandering what is wrong to this, my dropdown isn't showing in the navbar. im just wandering if somone can help me here for this problem, im still new here at html and css.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Curriculum </title>
<style>

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

#video-background {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto; 
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
}

.header{
    width: 1100px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: auto;
    }
.nav{
    width 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    overfow: auto;
    }
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: Maroon;
    opacity: .8;
    }
li{
    float: left;
    }
li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
    }
a:link{
    color: cyan;
    widht: 125px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-alignment: center;
    padding: 15px;
    text-transfrom: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: verdana; 
    }
li a {
    display: block;
    color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: cyan;
}

.active {
    background-color: White;
}


.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: Maroon;
    color: yellow;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: cyan;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted plays-inline>
  <source src="A.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div class  = "header">
<img src = "Header.jpg" width = "1100px" height = "150px">
<div class = "nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href = "Home.html #Home"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a href = "Mission_Vision.html #Mission & Vision"> Mission & Vision </a></li>
    <li><a href = "#"> Org.Chart </a></li>
    <li><div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Curriculum</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
    <li style="float:right"><a href="Contact.html#about">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

how do i fix this problem help me someone Thanks in advance for someone who can help me . i already copied some codes in some sites but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You've added `position: relative` to `.dropdown`.
 `.dropdown-content` is a child of `.dropdown` and is placed `absolute`

It therefor stays within the boundaries of it's parent, and therefor not visible.

Remove the `position: relative` and it works.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

#video-background {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto; 
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
}

.header{
    width: 1100px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: auto;
    }
.nav{
    width 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    overfow: auto;
    }
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: Maroon;
    opacity: .8;
    }
li{
    float: left;
    }
li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
    }
a:link{
    color: cyan;
    widht: 125px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-alignment: center;
    padding: 15px;
    text-transfrom: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: verdana; 
    }
li a {
    display: block;
    color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: cyan;
}

.active {
    background-color: White;
}


.dropdown {
    /*position: relative; < remove this line */
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: Maroon;
    color: yellow;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted plays-inline>
  <source src="A.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div class  = "header">
<img src = "Header.jpg" width = "1100px" height = "150px">
<div class = "nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href = "Home.html #Home"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a href = "Mission_Vision.html #Mission & Vision"> Mission & Vision </a></li>
    <li><a href = "#"> Org.Chart </a></li>
    <li><div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Curriculum</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
    <li style="float:right"><a href="Contact.html#about">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```